# консоль и браузер выдают разные часовые пояса. PHP

Tags: php, время

VDS Ubuntu 16.04 + VestaCP.
PHP-Скрипт возвращает время разных часовых поясов в зависимости от способа его запуска.

Скрипт 1.php:

```
<?php 
echo date('y-m-d H-i-s');
```

вызов из браузера site.ru/1.php выдает

18-10-11 01-44-16 - текущее время в моем часовом поясе (+3).

а вызов того же скрипта из командной строки ssh на сервере
~# php /путь_до_файла/1.php:

18-10-10 22-44-16 - текущее время по гринвичу (+0).

Настройки PHP /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini:

```
...
[Date]
date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"
...
```

Как заставить оба способа возвращать московское время +3 ?

Comment: команда ssh  ~# date возвращает дату/время (+3)

Comment: Ковыряй тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

> Скрипт возвращает время разных часовых поясов в зависимости от способа его запуска.

для разных способов запуска пхп использует разные конфиги. В случае использования вэб-севера, это приведенный вами `php.ini`, в случае же его использования в консоли это `php_cli.ini`. Поэтому убедитесь, что в последнем из них значение `timezone` соответствует желаемому.

Comment: спасибо, заработало.